# Incompatible value type id for Map error

Tags: trigger, map, sobject, schema

Anyone know why this keeps throwing an error?

```
list<Account>Dealerships = new list<Account>();

   map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> Opp2Deal = new map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>();
   map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> OLI2Deal = new map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>();
   map<Id,OpportunityLineItem> OliMap = new map<Id,OpportunityLineItem>();
   For(Id OppId : OppOLI.keyset())
   {      
       Opportunity opp = OppOLI.get(OppId);

       List<OpportunityLineItem>OLI = opp.OpportunityLineItems;


      integer j;
      for (OpportunityLineItem OppLI : OLI) 
      {
         Account acc = new Account(Name = Opp.Account.Id, Id = OLI[j].Dealership__c);
         Dealerships.add(acc);
         Opp2Deal.put(opp.Id, OppLI.Dealership__c);
         OLI2Deal.put(OppLI.Id, OppLI.Dealership__c);
         OliMap.put(OppLI.Id, OppLI);
      } 
       j++;
   }
```

I get the error on this line : `Opp2Deal.put(opp.Id, OppLI.Dealership__c);`

Also I must add that originally:

`map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> Opp2Deal = new map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>();` was `map<Id,Dealership__c>Opp2Deal = new map<Id, Dealership__c>();` But I was unable to create a map with a custom field (I did try using Schema.SObject, though I thought it would be better to keep it an OpportunityLineItem type and reference it by appending `.Dealership__c`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Opp2Deal` is a `map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>`, so it's expecting an `OpportunityLineItem` as the second argument in `Opp2Deal.put(opp.Id, OppLI.Dealership__c);`.

However, `OppLI.Dealership__c` is the `ID` of the Dealership record - not an `OpportunityLineItem`.

So, you need to change:

```
map<Id, OpportunityLineItem> Opp2Deal = new map<Id, OpportunityLineItem>();
```

To:

```
map<Id, Id> Opp2Deal = new map<Id, Id>();
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please go ahead and accept this as the solution to close the question.